# Is this a bad way to check prime number using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const input = 3;
let isPrime = true;
 outer: for(let i = 2; i < input; i++){
        for(let j = 2; j < input; j++) {
         if((i * j) === input) {
                  isPrime = false;
                  console.log(`${input} is Not a prime number`);
                  break outer;
              }
      }
}
if(isPrime) {
    console.log(`${input} is a prime number`); }
```

Personally, I think this is not the right way, even though I could've done it in an easier way, I approached the problem like so.
I needed some feedback from my seniors, can I get a code review?

Comment: yeah, it's bad. you can do it in `O(n)` time. you just need to check if any number from 2 to `input/2` can divide input.

Comment: It's fine it's just incredibly slow =). @nullptr if you are picking a simple limit, you can end on sqrt(input)

Comment: Related question: [Number prime test in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200089/number-prime-test-in-javascript)

Comment: @Evert an even better condition would be `i*i <= sqrt(input)` because `sqrt` is an expensive operation.

Comment: Loop till input/2. No need to go till Nth iteration

Comment: Questions has answer. Which was not good in term of memory and space.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out to fix my mistakes

Comment: @nullptr smart!

Comment: [Here's high-performance example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/prime-lib/blob/main/src/is-prime.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops are mostly time consuming solutions. If you have an other option you need to probably do that. In this case you using nested for loops to determine prime number. But you can do it with only one for loop.

```
const number = 3
let isPrime = true;

// check if number is equal to 1
if (number === 1) {
    console.log("1 is neither prime nor composite number.");
}

// check if number is greater than 1
else if (number > 1) {

  
    for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isPrime) {
        console.log(`${number} is a prime number`);
    } else {
        console.log(`${number} is a not prime number`);
    }
}
```

For more information you can check these links:
[Why nested loops are bad practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199196/why-are-nested-loops-considered-bad-practice)
[Finding a prime number](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/examples/prime-number)

Comment: (As already pointed out by @Evert in the comments below the question:) You do not need to try all numbers up to `number - 1`. Checking up to the square root is sufficient (so you could abort the loop at `i <= Math.sqrt(number)`).

Comment: @MartinHH I missed the comments thank you I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for investing your time for this

Comment: As nullptr pointed out, if Math.sqrt is slow you can also do `i * i < number` which will be the same but faster. If you do keep Math.sqrt, it's better to do that calculation once outside the loop instead of doing that check for every iteration.

Comment: Also instead of `i+` you can do `i+2`. Skip the even numbers.. Reduces the checks by half again. You could also skip any number ending in `0` or `5`, but not sure if that extra check is faster or slower.

If you need to check *many* numbers for prime, it's best to remember all previous prime numbers and only check against those instead of every number.