# Super B primes in range

Tags: python

So I have this problem involving Super B primes.
Super B prime is basically this.

- If n- is prime
- And sum of digits in n is prime
- And sum of digits in binary(n) is prime

Then n is Super B prime.
E.g.

- 41-is prime
- 4+1=5 -is prime
- 41(10)=101001(2) is 1+0+1+0+0+1=3 -is prime

=======

## So 41 is Super B prime.

The problem is that I have to print every Super B Prime in range(a,b) and what I have now exceeds the time limit by alot. How can I improve it?

```
import math
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache()
def is_prime(n):
    if n<1:
        raise ValueError("Must be positive integer")

    elif n>1:
        for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
        return True
@lru_cache()
def dec_to_binary(n):
    return int(bin(n)[2:])

a,b = map(int,input().split())
for i in range(a, b+1):
    l=0
    k=0
    for m in str(i):
        l=l+int(m)
    for o in str(dec_to_binary(i)):
        k=k+int(o)

    if is_prime(i) and is_prime(l) and is_prime(k):
        print(i)
```

Comment: This rather sounds like a case for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: But an obvious time improvement would be to test for divisibilty of 2 separately and then 3 + step 2. And why not store primes in a list and look them up instead of testing the same number several times?

Comment: `is_prime(i)` should be the last check as it is by far the most expensive

Comment: What ranges are allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:
Firstly, your prime check checks way too many numbers. The following implementation (derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime#answer-1801446)) is a decent trade-off between not diving into serious advanced math and not entirely stupid brute-forcing:

```
@lru_cache()
def is_prime(n):
    """Returns True if n is prime."""
    if n in (2, 3):
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
        return False
    i, w = 5, 2
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i, w = w + i, 6 - w
    return True
```

Secondly, you should do the cheap checks (primality of the much smaller digit sums) first and only do the primality check of the number itself if the others pass:

```
def bin_sum(n):
    return sum(map(int, '{0:b}'.format(n)))

def digit_sum(n):
    return sum(map(int, str(n)))

a, b = map(int, input().split())

for n in range(a, b + 1):
    # cheapest checks first
    if is_prime(bin_sum(n)) and is_prime(digit_sum(n)) and is_prime(n):
        print(n)
```