# Improve code to find prime numbers

Tags: python, performance, primes

I wrote this python code about 3 days ago, and I am stuck here, I think it could be better, but I don't know how to improve it. Can you guys please help me?

```
# Function
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True

    for d in range(3, int(n**0.5), 2):
        if n % d == 0:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: I would recommend reading up on Prime Sieve

Comment: You have a couple indentation errors, and indentation is very important in Python

Comment: [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n/2068548#2068548 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime/1801446#1801446

Comment: It depends how big the numbers are, and whether you just want to test a single number (or just a few numbers), or if you need to test a whole bunch of numbers that lie within a range. In the 1st case, your code is fine, in the latter case you should use a sieve, possibly a segmented sieve.

Comment: To test very large numbers you can use Miller-Rabin. Most implementations of that test are probabilistic for large numbers, but it's possible to do it deterministically. You can determine the primality of all n < 3,317,044,064,679,887,385,961,981, with these witnesses: (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good deterministic way to find *relatively small* prime numbers is to use a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

The mathematical principle behind this technique is the following: to check if a number is prime, it is sufficient to check that it is not divisible by other primes.

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    # Prepare our Sieve, for readability we make index match the number by adding 0 and 1
    primes = [False] * 2 + [True] * (n - 1)

    # Remove non-primes
    for x in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):
        if primes[x]:
            primes[2*x::x] = [False] * (n // x - 1)

    return primes[n]

    # Or use the following to return all primes:
    # return {x for x, is_prime in enumerate(primes) if is_prime}

print(is_prime(13)) # True
```

For reusability your could adapt the above code to return the `set` of all prime numbers up to `n`.

Comment: I tried this, but to find if a large number is prime, this method would actually slow the code, since it would have to find even another prime numbers, so:
If n is 500, it would check every prime less than 500, and compare it.
Sorry if I didn't mentioned I was looking for big numbers

Comment: @Locked You seem to misunderstand primes. The only deterministic way to check if a number is prime is to check its divisibility by other primes. This solution is the same as what sympy.isprime does and in particular: *it is faster*.

Comment: I see, but at least in my device, using sympy or even using the code that I first used is faster.
To check every number between 1 and 1000000, here's the results:
First code: About 3 seconds
Sympy: About 2 seconds
Using this method: More than 5 minutes

Comment: @Locked as stated, if you need to test for multiple numbers, just return the set of all primes, then one call is sufficient. sympy probably caches its sieve

Comment: @Locked see the commented return statement I added at the bottom of my function

Comment: This method works for small primes. For the large primes of thousands of bits used in cryptography this method is too slow to be useful. More advanced algorithms are used in that domain. If one must prove primality there are still advanced algorithms that are reasonably fast for large primes, such as elliptic curve primality proving or the more recent AKS-type algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, the speed of it is the same as Olivier Melançon's solution:

```
from math import sqrt; from itertools import count, islice

def is_prime(n):
    return n > 1 and all(n%i for i in islice(count(2), int(sqrt(n)-1)))

print(is_prime(5))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: I'm curious, what would be faster between using sympy and the slice-based sieve I wrote as answer? I don't have sympy, could you benchmark it?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Oh yeah you are right yours is much faster

Comment: I'm actually surprised, but glad to read this, I never benchmarked it, may I ask by how much?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon By about this much `0.8281598091125488`