# (Python 3) Spent an hour but couldn't find the error

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am a beginner at learning python 3 and I am just writing basic programs. I wrote this simple program which would take a number in and divide it by numbers starting from 1 to the square root of the number and find the remainders and add it to a list and print it.

```
import math

def prime_checker(num):
    n=1
    list_of_remainder=[]
    while n == math.floor(num**0.5):
        var=int(num % n)
        list_of_remainder.append(var)
        n += 1
    return list_of_remainder

var=prime_checker(10)
print(var)
```

Please tell me what I did wrong. I would like to point out here that I did try to research a bit and find error but I couldn't and only then have I posted this question.
The problem that I faced was that it printed out an empty list.

Comment: What's the problem? An error? Bad output? Being vague doesn't help us help you.

Comment: You have: `while n == math.floor(...)` shouldn't that be: `while n <= math.floor(...)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improve code to find prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752438/improve-code-to-find-prime-numbers)

Comment: [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) or any other debugger can help you identifying these kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

to start with, your while loop is not executed even once. The condition for your while loop is 
`while n == math.floor(num**0.5):`
The argument *num* you are passing to the function *prime_checker* is equal to 10. In this case your condition test is: 
`while 1 == math.floor(10**0.5)`
which is 
`while 1 == 3` which is obviously not true and as a result the loop is not executed even once.

Comment: Thanks...that helped!

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

def prime_checker(num):
    list_of_remainder = []
    number=num;
    n=1
    x=math.floor(number**0.5)

    while n <= x:

        v=int(number % n)

        list_of_remainder.append(v)
        n += 1

    return list_of_remainder

var=prime_checker(10)
print(var)
```