# how to remove composite numbers from a list in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, remove-method

I am not able to remove composite numbers from a list in python 3 .Can you help?

Example input:

```
list1 = [2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 23, 42, 46, 69, 138, 161, 322, 483]
```

Expected output:

```
list1 = [2, 3, 7, 23]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? I would start by creating a method which will return if a number is composite or not

Comment: Why are you not able? What have you tried?

Comment: Try to check prime

Comment: Also, [do **not** put "thanks" in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: [What is the best algorithm for checking if a number is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/)

Comment: @apomene I am a beginner and was stuck for two hours here. my method was not working as expected.

Comment: @roganjosh because i am a beginner. i tried to iterate through the list and check if the number is prime. the latter part didn't work as expected. i tried to alter it, but in vain

Comment: @user202729 i will take care of that. this was my first question, so i am not familiar to the rules here

Comment: Being a beginner is absolutely fine, but you will get a better reception if you show what you tried beforehand. I'm not a downvoter so I can only guess at their reasons. Even if it's completely broken; it does show that you actually tried _something_ to address your issue, and it gives a basis to explain why that logic didn't work.

Comment: @roganjosh ok. i will do that in my next questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `all`:

```
list1 = [2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 23, 42, 46, 69, 138, 161, 322, 483]
new_result = [i for i in list1 if all(i%c != 0 for c in range(2, i))]
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 7, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax1234's solution is correct, but instead of using range(2, i), I would add the modification that range(2, i) becomes range(2, 1+math.ceil(math.sqrt(i))), where the math module has been imported. For very large lists, this reduces the execution time since all composite numbers have factors less than or equal to 1+math.ceil(math.sqrt(i)).