# I wrote a C function to detemine whether a number is prime but it isn't working

Tags: c, primes

```
printf("enter number:");
scanf("%d",&number);

for(i=2;i<number;i++){      
    if(number%i==0)
        printf("your number isn't prime\n");
    else 
        printf("your number is prime\n");
}
```

I wrote this code.  The code runs but if I enter 10, it is printing many times that it isn't prime.

Comment: Can you explain what "asal" means? And also, you're getting number from the user, but using it further on. Is that intentional?

Comment: Asal means is Prime number.I think the problem is there. I want to know if a number is a prime number, but it enters it more than once.how can I fixed this problem.I want to write one time your count is prime or not but this code writes more.

Comment: Once you know that the number is _not_ prime, `break` the loop. Only report that the number is prime _after_ the loop if `i==sayi`.

Comment: it is working thanks for your help.

Comment: Sayi means is number. It is turkish word.

Comment: Have you tried running the program in your head?

Comment: If you enter `10`, he loop will check `if (number%2 == 0)` and report it isn't prime, then check `if (number % 3 == 0)` and report it is prime,  and so on, until it checks `if (number % 9 == 0)`.     So the behaviour your describe is exactly what the code SHOULD give.   If you want different behaviour, work out how to avoid printing out something on every loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Tip 1: try using a flag (but code would become longer,unnecessarily!)
Tip 2: simply put a break statement after your first printf ;)

Comment: ı'm really sorry. ı fıxed thıs code and ı was exticed because ı am new developer. ı m so sorry

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comment by DyZ you should break the loop once you know that the number is not a prime and only report that the number is prime AFTER the loop.

Additionally you do not have to check multiples of already checked divisors. if your number is not divisible by 2 it is not divisible by any multiple of 2 like 4, 6, 8 and so on.

also, check following already answered question on [prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime)