# Problem calling function to test in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm getting back into Python after some time away in Javascript. I'm currently trying to write a function that tests a set of numbers to see if they're prime.

I know how to do a simple function which does this, but I'm currently having some trouble understanding how to implement it into the test. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def first_100_prime_numbers():
    for prime in primes:
        if (prime > 2) & (prime % 2 != 0):
            return primes

def test():
    primes = set([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541])

    if set(first_100_prime_numbers()) == primes:
        print("Correct.")
    else:
        print("Answer is wrong. Keep trying!")

test()
```

Comment: '2 is the oddest of all primes'!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best algorithm for checking if a number is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I know how to check if a number is prime, just can't seem to figure out how to fit this algorithm inside the existing test.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: There's nothing in your code that is checking whether a number is prime. It's really not clear what your question is.

Comment: 1) you are not sending `primes list` to `first_100_prime_numbers` and neither its `global` so function first_100_prime_numbers *don't have access to primes list* 2) you are just *returning primes list* again back so answer will always be *correct*

Comment: Why are you wrapping the results in `set`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First things first

`a & b` executes the bitwise operator "and" between `a` and `b`. You are sure that you want to use the bitwise operator there? To apply the logical operator "and" between `a` and `b` you need to use `a and b`. Take a look on [this reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions).

## Check the identation

I tried to run your code with the corrections proposed by @SuperStew and it worked as expected, printing "Correct." on the console. I also noted that your code identation are not right and edited it. Maybe that was the problem.

## Last but not least

You know that this function of yours do not accomplish what you propose, right? You should check if the number is not divisible by all previous prime numbers too. That are other errors too but as far as I get that is not the point of the question.

Comment: Thanks so much mate. The bitwise operator and the indentation were definitely throwing things off (which I couldn't really tell with the in-browser IDE I'm using).

LOL it's also quite an early morning over here and I'm just now realizing that you're right; my function does not accomplish my goal. I guess I should've looked over it more myself before posting.

Comment: You're welcome, an answer acceptance would be appreciated  ;)

Comment: You got it mate :D
(That's the checkmark button, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Well in this line you need to give some argument

```
def first_100_prime_numbers():
```

needs to be like

```
def first_100_prime_numbers(primes):
```

and don't forget to actually pass it something when you call it

```
if set(first_100_prime_numbers(primes)) == primes:
```

Comment: Hmm I thought that was the solution but I keep getting that 'primes' is not defined' when i try to pass it in as an argument @SuperStew