# Why is my prime number checking code not displaying the correct output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, primality-test

I have a code that checks whether a number is prime or not, and outputs "Yes" or "No" accordingly. But when I input 1763, it outputs "Yes" even though it isn't a prime. The code checks whether a number is prime or not by checking if it can be divisible by any number between 2 and n-1. So when I input 1763, it should output "No" because 1763 can be divisible by 41. What went wrong in my code?

```
def getNumber():
    n=int(input())
    return n

def isPrime(n):
    if n==2:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        for i in range (2,n):
            if n%i==0:
                print("No")
                break
            else:
                print("Yes")
                break

def main():
    n = getNumber()
    isPrime(n)

main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best algorithm for checking if a number is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime)

Comment: You're breaking out of the for loop on the first iteration so it never gets down to 41

Comment: Your `for` loop breaks as soon as it finds a number that is not a factor. It needs to keep going until it finds a number that is a factor. You can only say it's prime after you have finished the whole for loop and not found any factors.

Comment: I took away the 2 breaks, and it still gives me the wrong output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not accounting for all the divisors. As soon as your first condition (`if n%i==0:`) is false, you execute the second `elif` condition and print "Yes".

Solution: You can use a flag which will be turned 1 **only** when a divisor will be found, which means the number is not prime. Below is slightly modified code of yours (showing only partial code, rest remains the same as yours). As pointed out by @bereal in the comments, you don't need to iterate up to `n` but only up to the square root `sqrt(n)`. `math.ceil` returns the closest rounded off integer.

```
import math
def isPrime(n):
    flag = 0
    if n==2:
        print("Yes")
        return
    else:
        # for i in range (2, n):
        for i in range (2, math.ceil(np.sqrt(n)) + 1):
            if n%i==0:
                print("No")
                flag = 1
                break

    if not flag:
        print ("Yes")
```

---

```
1763
No
```

Comment: It is actually enough to iterate until `sqrt(n)` inclusively.

Comment: @bereal: Indeed you are right. I just thought of rectifying OP's code without swaying away from the problem. But I can edit it. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: When you input 2, it outputs 2 "Yes"s.

Comment: @blhsing: I forgot to add 1 to the range. Now it should. Let me know if it still doesn't work for some number. Thanks for the comment though

Comment: You don't get it, it is outputting 2 "Yes". I only want it to output 1 "Yes".

Comment: @YolandaHui: I got it.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you break on the first iteration, even if you haven't been able to prove that it isn't a prime yet.

You need to print yes only after you've checked all possible divisors up to `n` (it's actually enough to only check all numbers upp to the square of `n`).

```
for i in range (2,n):
    if n%i==0:
        print("No")
        return
print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a number to be a prime only after you iterate through all the possible divisors without finding one. For that you can use the `for-else` construct instead, where the `else` block is only executed if the `for` loop isn't aborted with a `break` statement:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n==2:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        for i in range (2,n):
            if n%i==0:
                print("No")
                break
        else:
            print("Yes")
```