# Create a function to print a prime number with column and rows

Tags: php, function

i need a php function that can result like this.
example when i call the function

echo Prime(4,3);

```
2 3 5 7
11 13 17 19
23 29 31 37
```

anyone can help please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Be sure to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). As it is, your question is off-topic because you do not provide any code written by you. We can only help if you've tried to do something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best algorithm for checking if a number is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function primenumbers($n, $m){

$number = $n*$m;
    $numCounter = 0;
    $i = 0;
    while($numCounter < $number){
         $counter = 0; 
          for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
                if($i % $j==0){ 
                      $counter++;
                }
          }
        if($counter==2){
            print $i." ";
            $numCounter++;
        }
        if($numCounter % $m == 0){
        print  "<br>";
        }   
        $i++;

    } 

}
echo primenumbers(3,5);
```

Comment: i call the function primenumbers(3,5);
and this the result

2 3 5 7 11 13

the result have to be like this : 

2 3 5 7 11 13 -> rows[1]
17 19 23 29 31 -> rows[2]
37 41 43 47 51 -> rows[3]

Comment: @Rifano i updated it again now see it works as u expected ?

Comment: no change, still the same like before.. it result only one rows,

Comment: @Rifano nice to hear it. Please up vote this as well, if it is helpful. Happy coding