# What part of my code to filter prime numbers causes it to slow down as it processes?

Tags: performance, rust

I am doing some problems on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10). This challenge requires filtering prime numbers from an array. I was halfway near my solution when I found out that Rust was a bit slow. I added a [progressbar](http://a8m.github.io/pb/doc/pbr/struct.ProgressBar.html) to check the progress.

Here is the code: 
    extern crate pbr;

```
use self::pbr::ProgressBar;

pub fn is_prime(i: i32) -> bool {
    for d in 2..i {
        if i % d == 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}

pub fn calc_sum_loop(max_num: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut pb = ProgressBar::new(max_num as u64);
    pb.format("[=>_]");
    let mut sum_primes = 0;
    for i in 1..max_num {
        if is_prime(i) {
            sum_primes += i;
        }
        pb.inc();
    }
    sum_primes
}

pub fn solve() {
    println!("About to calculate sum of primes in the first 20000");
    println!("When using a forloop {:?}", calc_sum_loop(400000));
}
```

I am calling the `solve` function from my `main.rs` file. Turns out that the number of iterations in my for loop is a lot faster in the beginning and a lot slower later.

```
➜  euler-rust git:(master) ✗ cargo run --release
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.05s
     Running `target/release/euler-rust`
About to calculate sum of primes..
118661 / 400000 [===========>__________________________] 29.67 % 48780.25/s 6s
... 
...
400000 / 400000 [=======================================]     100.00 % 23725.24/s
```

I am sort of drawing a blank in what might be causing this slowdown. It feels like Rust should be able to be much faster than what I am currently seeing. Note that I am telling Cargo to build with the `--release` flag. I am aware that not doing this might slow things down even further.

Comment: What are you comparing this with? That algorithm is quite inefficient, so it will never beat, say, the Sieve of Eratosthenes, even in an interpreted language.

Comment: It gets slower as it goes along because you are calling `is_prime` (which has O(n) complexity) with higher and higher inputs.

Comment: Imho, you can not get it faster with this is_prime algorithm. Maybe you can look for better prime number checking algorithm or consider an external crate for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function which is slowing the execution is:

```
is_prime(i: i32)
```

You may consider to use more efficient crate like [primes](https://docs.rs/primes/0.2.3/primes/) or you can check efficient prime number checking algorithms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime)

Comment: I don't think there exist a know algorithm that could be called "efficient" for searching prime number, also this is a good thing because that would be the end of internet ;)

Comment: Haha you are right, but at least we can find a better solution then O(n) right :)