# Unexpected output - prime numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I wrote an answer to a program that gets a number from the user and display whether the number is prime.This is a beginner exercise.

Here is the question:

> A prime number is a number that is only evenly divisible by itself and 1. For example, the number 5 is prime because it can only be evenly divided by 1 and 5. The number 6, however, is not prime because it can be divided evenly by 1, 2, 3 and 6. Write a Boolean function named is_prime which takes an integer as an argument and returns true if the argument is a prime number, or false otherwise. Use the function in a program that prompts the user to enter a number then displays a message indicating whether the number is prime.

Program I wrote :

```
def main():
    # Get a number
    number = get_number()

    # Check the number is a prime
    status = is_prime(number)

    # Display a message if the number is prime or not
    display_prime(status)


def get_number():
    number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    return number


def is_prime(number):
    if (number % 1 == 0) and (number % number == 0):
        status = True
    else:
        status = False
    return status


def display_prime(status):
    if is_prime(status):
        print('The number is a prime')
    else:
        print('The number is not a prime.')


main()
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter a number: 6
The number is a prime
```

I can't find where I went wrong. Can you help me ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any number is this world is divisible by 1 and by itself. A prime number is a number which can never be divided by any other number other than itself or 1.  `6` is divisible by `6,1,2,3`, so it is not.

Comment: is_prime will return True for every number. Do you see what is missing there?

Comment: And a google search will give you enough examples to understand, how you should do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [checking prime number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558234/checking-prime-number-in-python)

Comment: You might also want to check what you're calling `display_prime` with.

Answer (score 2):

Where you went wrong is you ignored the word "only" in the definition of a prime number:

> A prime number is a number that is *only* evenly divisible by itself and 1

Every integer, prime or otherwise, is evenly divisible by itself and 1.  The difference is that a prime number is *only* divisible by itself and 1.  Because your function is simply checking that the input is divisible by itself and by 1, *every* input results in returning true.

What you want to do instead is write a function that determines that the number is *not* evenly divisible by any other number other than itself and 1.

There are some good examples of how to do that here:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/prime-number

Comment: Also, note that by definition a prime number has exactly two factors, itself and 1.  Therefore 1 is not a prime number, because it has exactly 1 factor, that is, 1.  So whatever your solution is, make sure that an input of 1 returns false.

Comment: @ James Dunn Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to call `is_prime` again in `display_prime`:

```
def get_int_input(prompt: str = 'Enter an integer number: ') -> int:
    number = -1
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input(prompt))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: Enter an integer, try again...')
    return number

def is_prime(number: int) -> bool:
    """Checks if a number is a prime by division"""
    if number < 2:
        return False
    if number == 2:
        return True
    for x in range(2, int(number**0.5) + 1):
        if number % x == 0:
            return False
    return True

def display_prime(prime_status: bool) -> None:
    """Displays a message if the number is prime or not"""
    if prime_status:
        print('The number is a prime.')
    else:
        print('The number is not a prime.')

def main() -> None:
    number = get_int_input()
    status = is_prime(number)
    display_prime(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Enter an integer number: 6
The number is not a prime.
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Enter an integer number: a
Error: Enter an integer, try again...
Enter an integer number: 2860486313
The number is a prime.
```

Comment: I'm sure your code works well. At the moment I can't understand it because I'm a newbie. Thank you for your comment. I will check later.

Comment: Ok, I understand I just added type information so the types of the parameters in your functions are clear.