# How to find a prime number using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have developed a code to find a prime number using python. But it keeps saying the numbers are prime even tho they are not. I am new to python so my knowledge in syntax is really not as good

when i input the number 15 it would say it is a prime number. but it shouldn't be a prime number

```
a = 0
#num will be the number we are checking
x = int(num)
num = sqrt(float(num))
num = int(num)
primeCheck = True
for a in range(3, num, 2):
    if x == 1 or x == 2:
        primeCheck = False
        #not prime
    if x % a == 0:
        primeCheck = False
        #not prime
if primeCheck == true:
    #prime
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n?rq=1).

Comment: There are many answers in SO about that, why don't you check those before asking again?

Answer (score 0):

You want `x % a`, not `a % x`. The larger number should almost always be on the left for the mod operation.