# How to create a list of prime numbers from a given list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I have a list of numbers `[7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 20, 23]` and I need to create a list of Prime numbers from given list.

I have written below code but this results `9` & `15` as prime too. I am not getting what I am missing here.

```
a = [7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 20, 23] 

x = []
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    num = a[i]
    for m in range (2,num):
        if (num % m)==0:
            break
        else:
            print('This is prime', num)
            x.insert(i, num)
            break
```

I Expect the output list x as `[7, 11, 13, 23]`.

Comment: This question (with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53451147/9225671)) has a few ways on how to calculate prime numbers in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `num % m != 0` doesn't mean that `num` is prime, it must be true for all possible `m` values (which can be reduced by going up to `num // 2`, and can even be reduced to go up to just `sqrt(num)`), for that, you can use a `for ... else` block (the `else` block will execute only when the `for` exits normally, without a `break`, which only happens with prime numbers):

```
a = [7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 20, 23] 

x = []
for num in a:   #   iterate with the value when you don't need the index
    for m in range(2, (num // 2) + 1):
        if num % m == 0:
            break
    else:
        print('This is prime', num)
        x.append(num)   #   use `append` to insert at the tail of the list

print(x)
```

Output:

```
This is prime 7
This is prime 11
This is prime 13
This is prime 23
[7, 11, 13, 23]
```

Comment: In short, what you _were_ doing was checking if the number was _even_.

Comment: My bad, I was not aware of for..else loop. Thanks!