# can we find prime number in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want a list of `n` numbers and check each item for primality and log whether the given number is prime or not. Unfortunately my below shown code is working incorrectly and I need help finding out why is it happening.

My code snippet:

```
l1 = []
num = int(input("Enter a range of numbers :: "))
for i in range(2, num + 1):
    l1.append(i)
for i in range(0, num - 1):
    for j in range(2, num):
        if l1[i] % j == 0:
            print(f'{l1[i]} is not a prime ')
            break
    else:
        print(f'{l1[i]} is a prime number')
```

Comment: for each `i`, for some `j` it will hold that `l1[i] == j` so for sure `l1[i] % j = 0`. I think you would want `j` to go **up until** `l1[i]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo so can you teach me the correct code for this?

Comment: There are many (many) resources online dealing with finding prime numbers. I am sure you will be able to find some useful ones to help you get the hang of it

Comment: I think this might help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do the loop that check if the number is prime for

```
for j in range(2, l1[i]):
```

Because here num have nothing to do with the check if it's prime.
So the complete code is :

```
l1 = []
num = int(input("Enter a range of numbers :: "))
for i in range(2, num + 1):
    l1.append(i)

for i in range(0, num - 1):
    for j in range(2, l1[i]):
        if l1[i] % j == 0:
            print(f'{l1[i]} is not a prime ')
            break
    else:
        print(f'{l1[i]} is a prime number')
```

For more info about algorithm to check if a number is prime, please refer to  :
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/how-to-create-the-most-compact-mapping-n-%E2%86%92-isprimen-up-to-a-limit-n)