# Prime numbers from 1 to n in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to find prime numbers from 1 to n, where is provided by user, I searched different sources on google I am working on the same logic but my logic shows all even numbers instead of prime

```
# prime number calculator

import time
userInput = int(
    input('Please Choose the number to find if its Prime or not: '))

flag = False


for i in range(2, userInput+1):
    if userInput % i == 0:
        flag = True
        break


if flag:
    print(f'{userInput} is not prime')
else:
    print(f'{userInput} is Prime')

choice = 'none'

while choice not in ['Y', 'N']:
    choice = input(
        f'want to display all prime numbers between {userInput} (y,n): ').upper()
        

listOfPrimes = [2,]

if choice == 'Y':
    for num in range(2, userInput+1):
        for i in range(2, num):
            if num % i == 0:
                break
            else:
                listOfPrimes.append(num)
                break
else:
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Good Bye')


print(listOfPrimes)
```

output - [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]

I am new to programming not sure where my logic fails

Comment: Take a look at this question. It might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68637037/does-anyone-know-why-my-program-doesnt-generate-the-correct-amount-of-prime-num

Comment: A search gives a lot of similar topics https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+Prime+numbers

Comment: Your first loop (checking a specific number) is also wrong. If the user enters, say, `5` then you run from 2 to 5 (inclusive) and check `userInput % i == 0`, the last iteration of which would be `5 % 5 == 0`, which will of course be true and the number will be reported as not prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner `for` loop is *always* going to execute a `break` on its first iteration, whether or not the `if` condition is false or true. In either case you `break`. So that means the loop will only do one iteration.

The second `break` should not be there. In fact, you should detect when the loop completes without doing the first `break`. For that, Python allows an `else` to be part of the `for`, which will exactly capture that case: when the loop exits normally (not via `break`) it will enter such an `else`:

```
for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        break
else:
    listOfPrimes.append(num)
```

Secondly, you should not *include* the number itself in the outer loop. You have this error also in the first part of the code. So change:

```
for i in range(2, userInput+1):
```

to

```
for i in range(2, userInput):
```