# Big integer prime checking algorithm

Tags: python, primes

I know this is a very repetitive question on here, but I was looking to understand if I could simply check for a big integer, (eg. 157,632,829) by check if its divisible by 2, 3, 5 or 7, or am I missing corner cases?

ie.

```
if (n < 4) :
        return True
if (n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0 or n % 7 == 0) :
        return False
```

Comment: yeah, how about `11 * 13`

Comment: Oh yes! so if i include 11 and 13 into the tests it should be good to go?

Comment: how about `17 * 19`

Comment: you have to check all the prime numbers all the way up until the `sqrt(num)`

Comment: primes are frequent, you'll have many numbers to check, otherwise you'll have `23*31`, `29*101`, `1999*2003` etc. cunterexamples

Comment: For really *huge* numbers, when loop (even up to `sqrt(n)`) is not an option, you can try *Rabin-Miller* test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test

Comment: you have to check all the prime numbers like that

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, Im looking to check this in a non-probabilistic manner, any way to do so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27946768/13000953

Comment: There are better *loop based* algorithms, e.g. Pollard Rho https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm; on no loops algorithms you can try Miller test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants, Adleman–Pomerance–Rumely,

Comment: If you're going to implement the Miller-Rabin test then bear in mind that it determines *probable* primality and is therefore not definitive

Comment: "Big integer" is unfortunately not specific enough. Different algorithms would be used depending on the size of the number being tested, and whether probabilistic answers are acceptable. For large enough integers the algorithms are fairly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a looped approach then you could try this. Runs in 6ms on my machine:

```
import math
import time

def gen_prime():
    D = {}
    q = 2
    while True:
        if q not in D:
            yield q
            D[q * q] = [q]
        else:
            for p in D[q]:
                D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
            del D[q]
        q += 1


def isprime(n):
    if n >= 2:
        g = gen_prime()
        s = int(math.sqrt(n))
        while True:
            d = next(g)
            if d > s:
                return True
            if n % d == 0:
                break
    return False

s = time.perf_counter()
r = isprime(157_632_829)
e = time.perf_counter()
print(f'{r} {e-s:.4f}s')
```

Note: The gen_prime() generator is not mine. Unfortunately I can't remember where I got it from so can't give credit

Answer (score 0):

A very simple routine would be

```
bool isprime( int n )
{
   for( int i = 2; i < n; i++ ) if( n % i == 0 ) return false;
   return true;
}
```

There are lots of ways to optimize it.